# QT Tab bar's top highlight with stylesheet

Tags: qt, tabs, stylesheet

I have a problem when trying to change the color of `QTabBar`'s top line (blue line in the picture below).

[image]

Is this a separate part of tabBar (like scroller or tear) or its top border ? And how can I change its color with styleSheet and leave the other parts of tabBar unchanged?

P.S. : My tabBar::styleSheet returns an empty string, so I can't get current style and make changes in it.

Comment: "style sheet" != style. All widgets require QStyle to be drawn. "Style sheet" is a convenience subclass of QStyle to let you style widgets using CSS files. Take whatever style you're using and find a way to change how it draws tabs (see also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

`setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected { selection-background-color: red; }");`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a "system" style, you may not be able to change the color of the line (cause representation of UI elements is not handled by Qt but by the system).

You should define a complete style for QTabBar (and maybe QTabWidget too) that you can customize as you wish.
See the [Qt Style Sheets Examples page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).